# FileWatcher 2 directories

Tags: c#

I have made a FileWatcher but my FileWatcher isn't working as planned and I am stuck.

I want to have a filewatcher that will work with 2 maps.

The code I have made myself won't choose the path I am saying he should choose.

In my application I need to browse to a location where he needs to check what happens with the files in that location.

My problem is: When I browse it wont watch the map I choose.

I think he already watches before I have chosen a path.

Please help.

(I just started working with C# for the first time)

If someone wants to help me but doesn't have enough information.

(I actually have 2 other files but this one looked the best)

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {     
   
  public Form1()

  {
  InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }      

  private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   

  }

  private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
  listBox1.Items.Add("File Created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
  }

  private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
  listBox1.Items.Add("File Changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
  }
  private void fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {

  listBox1.Items.Add("File Deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);

  }

  private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
  {

  listBox1.Items.Add("File Renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);

  }

  private void fileSystemWatcher2_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
  listBox1.Items.Add("File Changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);

  }

  private void fileSystemWatcher2_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
  listBox1.Items.Add("File Created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
  }

  private void fileSystemWatcher2_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
  listBox1.Items.Add("File Deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
  }

  private void fileSystemWatcher2_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
  {
  listBox1.Items.Add("File Renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  //
  DialogResult resDialog = dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog();
  if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
  {
  textBox1.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
  }
  }

  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  DialogResult resDialog = dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog();
  if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
  {
  textBox2.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
  }
  }    

  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is you're never setting the `Path` of `fileSystemWatcher1`, so in one of the button clicks, after you get the path back, do this:

```
fileSystemWatcher1.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
```

However, your next problem is that you're wanting to use one `FileSystemWatcher` to watch **two** paths, that can't be done, you'll need a second one to watch both. However, they could both consume the same event handlers. So once you have a second one, in the other button click you haven't already used, add this:

```
fileSystemWatcher2.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
```

Comment: Thanks man. It worked and about the button it should be monitored when i start the application but i just added those 2 lines and it worked! THANKS!